# Show that $\exp(\overline{z}) = \overline{\exp(z)} $

Tags: complex-numbers

Given that $z \in \mathbb{C}$, I want to show that  $\exp(\overline{z}) = \overline{\exp(z)} $. For LHS I can see that we will get some real number as $\overline{z}$ is some real number. But should RHS be a complex number which is a complex conjugate of $e^z$? If so how can this equality hold?

Comment: \begin{align}e^{\overline{x+iy}}&=e^{x-iy}\\&=e^x(\cos{(y)}-i\sin{(y)})\\\end{align}\begin{align}\overline{e^{x+iy}}&=\overline{e^x(\cos{(y)}+i\sin{(y)})}\\&=e^x(\cos{(y)}-i\sin{(y)})\\\end{align}

Comment: $\overline{z}$ is not real (unless $z$ itself is real). What do you think $\overline{z}$ means?

Comment: If you define the exponential to be an entire function, this is a general property of entire functions of real coefficients. But you should give us your definition.

Comment: @PeterForeman: mh, this is a little like "it is true for all complex because it is true for the imaginaries", just displacing the question a little.

Answer (score 2):

Another proof.
$$
e^z\quad\text{and}\quad\overline{\;e^{\overline{z}}\;}
$$
are two analytic functions that agree on the real line.  By the identity theorem, they agree everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Using the expansion of $z$ as a slightly different way of obtaining the answer, write 
$$
e^z = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\;z^k
$$
Thus
\begin{align}
\overline{e^z} &= \overline{\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\;z^k} \\
               &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \overline{\;\frac{1}{k!}\;}\;\overline{z^k}\\
               &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\;{\overline{z}\;}^k\\
               &= e^{\overline{z}}
\end{align}